# Creating Dynamic Header with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, header

I am trying to create a header that adjusts its contents as the user makes the window smaller, and eventually goes down to just a menu icon at under 850px. The problem is that the header is always the last thing to load on the page with my current Jquery code. Any ideas?

```
   $( window ).bind("resize load",function() {
    if($(window).width()>1050){
      $('.three-head').show();
      $('.two-head').css("margin-right","90px");
      $('#header').show();
      $('.big-head').show();
      $('.small-head').hide();
    }
else if($(window).width()<1050 && $(window).width()>850){
    $('.two-head').css("margin-right","30px");
    $('#header').show();
    $('.big-head').show();
    $('.small-head').hide();
    $('.three-head').hide();
    $('.four-head').show();
    $('.five-head').show();
}
else if($(window).width()<850){
    $('.small-head').show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

and remove

```
 $( window ).bind("resize load",function()
```

is load after window load

Answer (score 0):

I would try a dynamic function .resize() that will lisen to your window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width()>1050){
            $('.three-head').show();
            $('.two-head').css("margin-right","90px");
            $('#header').show();
            $('.big-head').show();
            $('.small-head').hide();
        } else if($(window).width()<1050 && $(window).width()>850){
            $('.two-head').css("margin-right","30px");
            $('#header').show();
            $('.big-head').show();
            $('.small-head').hide();
            $('.three-head').hide();
            $('.four-head').show();
            $('.five-head').show();
        }
    });
});
```

You can also implement a onLoad function lik this:

```
$('#header').load(function () {

    YOUR CODE HERE

)}
```

Hope this helps